# How can I best represent French addresses?

Tags: addresses, l10n

I have a list of postal addresses to import, many of which are French.  In the "State" column, I have the region - but the list of state/provinces for France in CiviCRM is departments, not regions.  I don't have the departments.

How do French CiviCRM users record the region?  Or do they?  Is region or department more important than the other?  It seems like neither are necessary for sending postal mail.